# On state upadte React native setState method not calling render function

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, state

Scenario:: I am trying to make a todo list app using react native, in which I store the input data that is the particular 'todo' in the `AsyncStorage`.

Now when I try to change the items in the state the render method gets called and the view that is the list gets updated.

But when the `mylist` is Null that is `AsyncStorage` is empty I change the `status` to in the state to `Null` expecting it render again and show that `Hurray !! No todos left!!`.

Code Snippet where I update the state:

```
 if(filtered.length === 0){
      console.log('Before Updating state ',this.state);
      this.setState({
        status :'Null',
        items: [],
        blank : 1,
      })
      console.log('After Updating state ',this.state);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  AsyncStorage,
  Alert,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import {
  Appbar,
  IconButton,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Card,
  List
} from "react-native-paper";
export default class App extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    if (await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist")).length) {
      this.array = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist"));
      this.setState({
        items: await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist"))
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        status: "Null"
      });
    }
    this.id = this.array.length - 1;
  }
  array = [];
  id = 0;
  state = {
    items: [{ id: 0, data: "No todos today!!!" }],
    text: "",
    blank: ""
  };
  handleDelete = async id => {
    const objectarray = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist"));
    const filtered = objectarray.filter(data => {
      if (data.id === id) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    // console.log('Filtered array of objects':filtered)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("mylist", JSON.stringify(filtered));
    this.setState({
      items: await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist"))
    });
    if (filtered.length === 0) {
      console.log("Before Updating state ", this.state);
      this.setState({
        status: "Null",
        items: [],
        blank: 1
      });
      console.log("After Updating state ", this.state);
    }
    this.array = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist"));
  };
  storedata = async () => {
    // console.log(e.target);
    if (this.state.text !== "") {
      this.id = this.id + 1;
      this.array.push({ id: this.id, data: this.state.text });
      this.setState({
        text: "",
        status: ""
      });
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("mylist", JSON.stringify(this.array));
      this.array = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist"));
      this.setState({
        items: await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist"))
      });
    } else {
      Alert.alert("Alert", "Field Empty");
    }
  };

  render() {
 if(this.state.status !== "Null"){
    var list = this.state.items.map(iterator => {
      console.log("I am in there in the list");
      if (this.state.status !== "Null") {
        console.log("i am in the list if ");
        return (
          <View>
            <Card key={iterator.id} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
              <List.Item
                title={iterator.data}
                left={() => <List.Icon icon="label" />}
                right={() => (
                  <IconButton
                    icon="delete"
                    animated="true"
                    onPress={() => this.handleDelete(iterator.id)}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Card>
          </View>
        );
      } else {
        console.log("i am in the list else");
        return (
          <View>
            <Card key="Null" style={{ margin: 10 }}>
              <List.Item
                title="Hurray !! No todos left!!"
                left={() => <List.Icon icon="label" />}
              />
            </Card>
          </View>
        );
      }
    });
   }
  else{
      var list = () => {
      return(
        <View>
        <Card key="Null" style={{ margin: 10 }}>
          <List.Item
            title="Hurray !! No todos left!!"
            left={() => <List.Icon icon="label" />}
          />
        </Card>
      </View>
      )
    }
  }
  }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Appbar.Header>
          <Appbar.Content title="My Todos" subtitle="Todos" />
        </Appbar.Header>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
          <TextInput
            label="Add Todo"
            mode="outlined"
            value={this.state.text}
            color="white"
            style={{ margin: 30 }}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text: text, blank: "" })}
          />
          <Button
            mode="outlined"
            icon="label"
            onPress={this.storedata}
            style={{ marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30, marginBottom: 30 }}
          >
            Add Todos
          </Button>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <ScrollView>{list}</ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3"
  }
});
```

My console :

[image]

I am a beginner to React Native and would appreciate any help and suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem is you are also set items(state) to empty Array [], So it is not iterating your mapping function that is why your else part will never execute if items(state) are set to [], You have to separate out both

Comment: Okay , I tried putting another If else block outside the` map` function but it didn't work!! Can you help me with this please ?? @NimeshBhalani

Comment: Just put if block I think it will work

Comment: I have updated the code can you have a look , it is still the same !@NimeshBhalani

Comment: There is a problem in else block you have declared list(var) as a function and second issue is you have to declare list(var) first before if block then you can assign view as per condition

Comment: But the list is an React.Component element  , how can I declare it without using a fucntion?@NimeshBhalani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209921/discussion-between-dev-and-nimesh-bhalani).

Comment: Your welcome. Have a nice day